# Monodroid endless list

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I'm pretty new to monodroid and I was wondering how you can make a list that load new items if you reach the bottom. Can someone give me some guidlines how I should handle this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have not (yet) used it personally I kept a bookmark on this [blog / sample](http://www.elucidsoft.com/blog/2011/08/31/infinitelistview-mono-android/). Let us know if this helps :-)

Comment: Hi poupou, sorry for the late response, but your post did give me some good ideas, so many thanks :-)